# Run multiple lineinfile commands with with_items

Tags: ansible, devops

How can I achieve the following in ansible? I want to run multiple lineinfile within a list of servers.

If I do the following, ansible complains because of the repeated `lineinfile`

```
- name: ensure /etc/environment is correct
  tags: env
  with_items: "{{ hosts }}"
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/environment regexp=^PROFILE=line=PROFILE={{prof}}
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/environment regexp=^OTHER=line=OTHER={{other}}
```

I tried to nest `with_items` to no avail.

Comment: Please describe what `groups['app']` mean in your example? To run a task on a list of servers in ansible you use `hosts:` parameter of a play. To run the same task with different parameters you use `with_items:` and `{{item}}` placeholder in your task's parameters. If you want nested loops (e.g. change several different lines for some different apps in a file), you use `with_nested:` [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops). In any case name of task (`lineinfile` in your example) always specified only once.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov instead of `groups[app]` it can be `hosts`. I want to run *several similar tasks* on a list of servers. I didn't get any luck using `with_nested`, can you provide an example on this case?

Comment: `lineinfile` is an anti pattern. You should consider `template`.

Comment: What is your ansible version?

Comment: I'm using Ansible 2.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the example playbook to ensure file /tmp/testfile has PROFILE set to my_new_profile and OTHER set to my_new_other on both server1 and server2:

```
- hosts: server1, server2
  tasks:
    - lineinfile: dest=/tmp/testfile regexp={{item.regex}} line={{item.replace_with}}
      with_items:
        - regex: ^PROFILE=
          replace_with: PROFILE=my_new_profile
        - regex: ^OTHER=
          replace_with: OTHER=my_new_other
```

**Update:** using dynamic group and nested loop to create two files: testfile_host1 and testfile_host2 with lines present on all servers in my_dynamic_group group created earlier in playbook.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - add_host: name={{ item }} groups=my_dynamic_group
      with_items:
        - server1
        - server2

- hosts: my_dynamic_group
  tasks:
    - lineinfile: dest=/tmp/testfile_{{ item[0] }} regexp={{item[1].regex}} line={{item[1].replace_with}} create=yes
      with_nested:
        - [ 'host1', 'host2' ]
        - [
            { regex: '^PROFILE=', replace_with: 'PROFILE=my_new_profile' },
            { regex: '^OTHER=',   replace_with: 'OTHER=my_new_other' }
          ]
```

Comment: I cannot use this because I am already using different `{{hosts}}`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this, but I've updated my answer with dynamic group and nested loop example.